# long-time pending transaction suddenly is hidden on Goerli

Tags: gas, infura, pending-transactions, web3-providers, goerli

**Sometimes**, happen for me scenario below:

I send a transaction to Goerli with low gas. Infura nodes return me a successful message with a related transaction hash. But when I search for the transaction on goerli.etherscan it does not exist, while the transaction is in a pending state because, after about one day when the transaction is successful, I can see the transaction on goerli.etherscan which is a success state.